# When is $(m+1)/2$ a quadratic residue mod $m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

The motivation here comes from [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872586/find-a-positive-integer-n-m-p-q-p-neq-q-m1-such-that-p-and) involving a set of divisibility constraints. In particular, it requires finding $n,p,q$ such that $p \mid 2n^2-1$ and $q \mid 2n^2-1$. Since $2n^2-1$ is always odd, $2$ is invertible, and these can be rearranged to the following:

$$n^2 \equiv 2^{-1} \pmod m \equiv \frac{m+1}{2} \pmod m$$

where $m$ is either $p$ or $q$ as needed. From a quick perusal up to $10000$, it seems this hold true when $m$ is a prime of the form $\pm 1 \pmod 8$, or the product of such primes. Interestingly, this is the same set of moduli for which $2$ is a quadratic residue.

There are supplements to quadratic reciprocity for $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3$, and many others, but I don't know of one for $(m+1)/2$. Does this form follow the rule it appears to? As a sub-question, is this *generally* true for inverses of quadratic residues? That would seem pretty wild.

Comment: Note that $2n^2\equiv 1\pmod{m}\;\to\;4n^2\equiv 2\pmod{m}\;\to\;(2n)^2\equiv 2\pmod{m}$. Thus, as you noted, it would be the same set of moduli for which $2$ is a quadratic residue. Regarding this being true for inverses, that's the case since, from multiplying both sides by $a^2$, we get for any $a$ where $\gcd(a,m)=1$ that $a^{-1}\equiv x^2\pmod{m} \iff a\equiv (ax)^2\pmod{m}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, that's a pretty succinct proof that the subquestion is true. Maybe I missed it when searching, as it seems pretty simple.